# How can I filter a table using an aggregate function in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

I have a dataset with data for an 2 events. The dataset includes the lead  time (number of weeks prior to event date that each order is placed).

I'm trying to use the following in a tablex filter:

```
Expression: lead_time
Operator: <=
Value: =Max(IIF(Fields!performance_code.Value = Parameters!vc_performance_name.Value, Fields!lead_time.Value, -100))
```

When I try I get the error: A FilterValue for the tablix includes an aggregate function. Aggregate functions cannot be used in dataset filters or data region filters.

I can apply the filter I want to the detail "row group" and it correctly hides the rows I don't want, but they continue to be included in the totals.

Is there a way I can remove them completely?

**Example Data**

```
performance_code, lead_time, amt
1, -10, 100
1, -5, 100
1, -3, 10
1, -1, 1000
2, -9, 50
2, -4, 100
```

My Parameters!vc_performance_name.Value in this instance is 2 and hence the MAX value should be -4.

In english this basically means we are 4 weeks away from the event date and i only want to see data for performance 1/2 with lead times of -4 or less...

**Output would look something like**

```
performance_code, lead_time, amt
1, -10, 100
1, -5, 100
2, -9, 50
2, -4, 100
```

Comment: Can you add some example data and expected results for different parameter selections? Just a few rows - enough to show the problem. I'm just having a tough time translating the requirements and the expression above without some more context.

Comment: I've added an example. Helpful?

Comment: I'm not really following your example enough to answer, but why not filter the totals too? Sum(iif(cond,fieldtosum,0), scope)

Comment: i've simplified the data, there are quite a lot of columns, and various group levels that i'll need to update rather than just the single filter i'd like to be able to...

Comment: Can you do it on the SQL side?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing, but can't see why I wouldn't be able to do it in SSRS (the subquery i've had to use is pretty horrible)

Comment: If you were able to hid the data you wanted to hide - Could you not have used " =Sum(IIF(<Condition of Visibility Hidden expression>, 0, Fields!ItemToBeSum.Value)) ?

Comment: You certainly can but it seems mad to have to do these "workarounds" instead of what I actually want to do... Filter the data :)

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you may amend your select statement and add a separate field with the max lead time for each performance code and then filter the data based on this value